# Use Azure Function to Export CSV

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I was trying to write an azure function that access azure blob storage, and use the generated url. So that once the user put this url, it will download a csv file from azure Blob Storage to the caller's local PC.
From the azure function I wrote so far it is able to access the data on the blob storage. Does anyone know how to have it export csv to the calling user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is quick `conversion` that might help for you

```
import azure.functions as func

async def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    // access azure blog storage and get the csv read as string
    filebytes= bytes(csv, 'utf-8')

    return func.HttpResponse(body=filebytes, status_code=200, mimetype='application/octet-stream')
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to create `FileContentResult`

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    string csv;

    //Access azure blog storage and create in csv content

    byte[] filebytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csv);

    return new FileContentResult(filebytes, "application/octet-stream") {
        FileDownloadName = "Export.csv"
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Do you know how to do this in Python code?